# Is there an alternative to Application Switcher with search?

Tags: macos, application-switcher

On Windows, I've been using [Switcher](http://insentient.net/) and the one feature that I really like is being able to switch to applications by typing in portions of their title. Is there an application for Mac OS X (10.7) that provides similar functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Alfred (free)](http://itunes.apple.com/en/app/alfred/id405843582?mt=12)

- find any application or file
- this app will learn and prioritize your searches
- system commands and extended features (google search, bitly...)
- you can get more powerful features when purchasing the [powerpack](http://www.alfredapp.com/powerpack/)

[image]

## [Quicksilver (free)](http://qsapp.com/)

- find any application or file
- this app will learn and prioritize your searches
- lots of **free** [plugins](http://qsapp.com/plugins.php) with extend the functionalities

  - move files
  - execute bash commands
  - ...

[image]

## Spotlight (built-in)

...which is part of the OS and be triggered using <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> (default shortcut).

[image]

Comment: Not to be too picky, but all of these apps only switch by Application Name, not Window Title. Ideally, I would like to use document names or web page titles to switch between apps.